# Duplicate columns in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm pulling a ResultSet from a MySQL database and attempting to dynamically build a TableView on a key down event.  It works fine the first time I trigger it, but all subsequent times it creates duplicates of my initial columns while changing the row data for each column to match the new ResultSet. I want the TableView to be cleared completely every time this build function is run.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });

            tableView.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

        while(rs.next())
        {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            row.removeAll(row);
            for(int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row );
            data.add(row);
        }

        tableView.setItems(data);
```

Things I tried:

- Watching the value of ObservableList data, which is empty as it is
  reinstantiated everytime the function is executed
- Clearing the columns of the TableView using tableView.getColumns.removeAll()

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the current columns before you start adding them:

```
table.getColumns().clear();
for(int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    columnCita.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cita"));
    columnLast.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ultimavisita"));
    columnImporteF.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("precio"));

    columnCita.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(15));
    columnLast.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(6));
    columnImporteF.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(9));
```

in my case the wrong is in the next line. becose already i had added the columns.

```
    table.getColumns().addAll(columnCita, columnLast, columnImporteF);
```

the problem is you are adding the columns again.